# TypeOf Char does not return true when checking param of type char

Tags: vb.net, char, typeof

In a VB.NEt program I am working on I have these lines:

```
Dim objectType = parameters(2).GetType()

' here objectType is of type System.Char

If TypeOf parameters(2) Is Char() Then
    enrgAEcrire = parameters(2)
Else

    Throw New Exception("@MSG 12,9: INVALID PARAM")
End If
```

The objective is that I need to validate the second parameter is indeed a char. However if I set the parameter like this before hitting these lines:

```
Dim myVar As String = "S"c
```

When the line is hit, `objectType` = `System.Char` but the exception is thrown nonetheless.

I need to know if it is a common VB.Net error / behavior before validating the problem.

Comment: is `parameters` a string or string array?

Comment: You don't say how `parameters` is declared, but in `Dim MyVar As String = "S"c` you have certainly declared MyVar as a String rather than a Char. Assign `"S"c` to MyVar doesn't change the type of `MyVar`.

Comment: Oh no? Oh! How do I declare a char value on a string in vb.net @Blackwood ?

Comment: A variable can be a Char or a String, but not both. If you want to check that a String consists only of a single character, check that its Length is 1. `If myVar.Length = 1 Then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something on the lines of:

```
    If parameters(2).GetType() Is GetType(Char) Then
        enrgAEcrire = parameters(2)
    Else

       Throw New Exception("@MSG 12,9: INVALID PARAM")
    End If
```

Note that the second GetType (`GetType(Char)`) is equivalent to the C# `typeof`; but the first `GetType` (`parameters(2).GetType()`) is used identically in both VB.NET and C#.

Comment: Ah, ok! I will try this out.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you :)